# Overloading operator <

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I experts, once again while practicing online, i encountered another problem. This is regarding function template. I am able to create the template but i am not sure how to overload appropriate operator. Please advise.

Question

A function template **largestOfTree** to return the largest of 3 elements of the same parameterised type. To what class can the function template be applied? Write a class **trainEngine** with fields for **name,model,mass**. Overload the appropriate operator so the **largestOfThree** function template can be applied to three **trainEngine** objects.

So far ?

```
 template<class T>
 bool largestOfThree(T t1, T t2, T t3){
  if(t1<t2&&t2<t3){
  return true;
   }else{
    return false;
  }
 }
```

trainEngine

```
class trainEngine {
private:
string name;
string model;
string mass;
public:
friend bool operator<(trainEngine const& lhs) {
if (lhs.name<lhs.model&&lhs.model<lhs.mass){
return true;
}
```

};

Comment: To which classes the function can be applied depends largely on the implementation of the function, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think i can indicate that we can use the template for any class.

Comment: You are asking "To what class can the function template be applied" and I am saying "it depends largely on the implementation of the function". If the function simply returned a `T()` then it would work for all classes with a default constructor and a copy constructor. It if called `t1.foo()` then you'd have extra constraints.

Answer (score 3):

A `friend operator<` is going to be non-member and should thus be binary.  Moreover, you forgot the return type.  You likely want:

```
friend bool operator<(trainEngine const& lhs, trainEngine const& rhs) {
    // implementation
}
```

This would go where your `operator<` declaration is currently.

[Here](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/fncpp/OperatorOverloading) is a list of idiomatic signatures for operator overloads, and a more elaborate explanation of what juanchopanza mentioned in the comments.  Note that the non-member operators can be defined within the class body if they are marked as friends.  (They are still non-member functions if you do this.)

Comment: +1. And it is better to have a non-member binary operator rather than a member one for symmetry between LHS and RHS.

Comment: @AntonGolov Than how can i code the template part. Is it correct to take in 3 parameters

Comment: @user1571494 The template is just a matter of finding which of `t1`, `t2` and `t3` is the greatest.  For instance, if `t1 < t3 && t2 < t3`, then `t3` is apparently the largest.

Comment: @AntonGolov  I have updated my questions with your input. Is it correct

Comment: @user1571494 after your edits, your function should probably be renamed `isSortedInAscendingOrder`.

Comment: @user1571494: No; that's simply one case.  Seeing as this is clearly some sort of exercises, I'm not going to provide the full solution.  Write the function as you would for `T` being `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you overload operator '`<`', you  should also overload operator '`>`'

and you have to write return type bool also.

```
 friend bool operator<(trainEngine const& obj1, trainEngine const& obj2)
```

In fact, it’s convention in most code to prefer the usage of `<` over `>` But more generally, always overload the complete set of related operators; in your case, this would probably also be `==`, `!=`, `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: Your comparison function is unary, so it wouldn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Let me note that **currently your implementation only depends on the right-hand-side** (which you call lhs!). It is surely not what you want.

I think you wanted something like this:

```
bool operator<(trainEngine const& rhs) {
  if(name!=rhs.name) 
    return(name<rhs.name);
  if(model!=rhs.model)
    return (model<rhs.model);
  return (mass<rhs.mass);
}
```

or the **friend version**:

```
//within the class
friend bool operator<(trainEngine const& lhs, trainEngine const& rhs);

//outside the class
bool operator<(trainEngine const& lhs, trainEngine const& rhs) {
  if(lhs.name!=rhs.name) 
    return(lhs.name<rhs.name);
  if(lhs.model!=rhs.model)
    return (lhs.model<rhs.model);
  return (lhs.mass<rhs.mass);
}
```